# Can't create a collapsable navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See the below fiddle. I think I'm getting confused on how to create a collapsable navbar (showing the hamburger menu on smaller devices. What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/xnxcwqyp/

html:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="navbar" id="c-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="logo" href="/">Logo</a>
    <nav>

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <!--//nav-toggle-->
      </div>
      <!--//navbar-header-->

      <div class='navbar-collapse collapse' id='navbar-collapse'>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a class="header-text" href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="header-text" href="/section">Practice</a></li>
          <li><a class="header-text" href="/login">Log in</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Do you explain clearly that is needed exactly... and all things are working good..

Comment: It's working, do you have jQuery linked ?

Comment: You have to link jQuery as other users have told you and the hamburger menu is not seen because missing Bootstrap classes at the `nav` tag: `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

Comment: got it. That fixed things but I included navbar-default in my header. Should I just delete the header and move all the classes and id's there to my nav?

Answer (score 0):

Just add jQuery and this should work :

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ze5ju72n/

Comment: oh boy... okay. I'm actually using rails to develop this so this is troublesome because I can't just add jquery like that. Strange because I definitely included jquery in my rails app. Guess this is a question for another tag then.